# config.getInitParameter always return null

Tags: java, servlets

Why does `config.getInitParameter(String)` always return `null` in the following code example?

```
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException
{
    super.init(config);
    filename = config.getInitParameter("addressfile");
```

This is web.xml file

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>ListManagerServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>savva.listmanagerservlet.ListManagerServlet</servlet-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>addressfile</param-name>
    <param-value>d:\temp\demo.txt</param-value>
</init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>ListManagerServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/ListManagerServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

UPD: Eclipse EE Indigo, Java 1.6, Tomcat 7.0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The canonical way is to just use the inherited [`GenericServlet#getInitParameter()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html#getInitParameter%28java.lang.String%29) in the argumentless [`init()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html#init%28%29) method (and **remove** any `init(config)` method).

```
@Override
public void init() throws ServletException {
    filename = getInitParameter("addressfile");
}
```

If that still doesn't work, then your `web.xml` is not properly been deployed, or you have a typo in the parameter name, or you actually accessed a different instance variable than `filename` to use/test it.

Comment: I`ve done init(). But the result is the same. Return null. I develop in Eclipse, and tomcat use from eclipse also. Web.xml don`t deploy in tomcat. May be this is characteristic develop in Eclipse?

Comment: Then pay attention to the last paragraph of my answer. My bet that your `web.xml` is not properly rebuilt/redeployed after the edit.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure your servlet is calling super.init(config) on its init method, else it won't work.

Comment: Wrong,the config referred while get is function parameter which is passed by container.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have really deployed the proper web.xml. Also check with `config.getInitParameterNames()` what parameters have been found.

Comment: config.getInitParameterNames() Returns an empty Enumeration.

Comment: How can i sure, that really deployed the proper web.xml? I develop in Eclipse with Eclipse`s tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

It's never a good idea to override the `init(config)` method. Instead use the provided `init()` convenience method and do a `getServletConfig()` to get the configuration parameters:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.2.1/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html#init()
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.2.1/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html#getServletConfig()

Answer (score 0):

If use the IDE STS4, checkout if annotation on the class name exists, use BOTH "annotation" and "web.xml" may cause the value null.